# Как хранить часть проекта в отдельном репозитории?

Tags: git

Имеется проект, который ведется в приватном репозитории. Проект поделен на модули, и в каждом модуле есть файл с локализацией.

Задача состоит в том, чтобы выделить эти файлы в отдельный репозиторий для переводчика. Т.е., чтобы при изменении файлов локализации можно было бы просто запушить файлы в репозиторий с переводами, а после того, как переводчик переведет файлы, получить их назад.

И чтобы при этом в репозиторий с переводами не попадали файлы с кодом.

Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: посмотрите git submodules

Comment: Я смотрел в эту сторону, но, к сожалению, переводы не имеют отдельной директории а перемешаны вместе с кодом программы, т.е. у меня есть модуль у него отдельная папка, в ней лежат файлы модуля, в том числе и перевод. Есть другой модуль, у него своя папка, и свой файл перевода и так далее...

Comment: это вряд ли можно решить без изменения архитектуры приложения

Comment: Если работаете под линуксом, то можно сделать следующее - создать репозиторий, где хранить только переводы. Подцепить это все сабмодулем. А для того, что бы нужные файлы были в нужных местах - прицепить их симлинками. Но это плохо поддерживаемое решение. С другой стороны, никто не мешает доделать скрипт сборки так, что бы он копировал переводы перед сборкой.

Comment: KoVadim, да, скорее всего это единственное решение

Comment: По-моему держать переводы в отдельном репозитории не очень логично, переводчики ведь могут прислать пулл-реквест с переводами; для чего вам именно так?

Comment: andreymal, да, я согласен, дело в том, что переводчик не умеет пользоваться гитом. Поэтому мы используем сервис lingohub, в качестве прослойки. Ну а передавать весь проект стороннему сервису не кошерно, поэтому и возникла проблема с отдельным репозиторием

Answer (score 4, accepted):

если в качестве способа интеграции репозиториев рассматривать систему [подмодулей git](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-Git-%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B8), то возможны как минимум три варианта организации структуры:

1. создать один репозиторий, в котором файлы с переводами для ваших модулей будут разложены по под-каталогам вида `module1`, `module2` и т.д., и подключить его как git-подмодуль, например, в каталог `translations` в, например, корне основного репозитория.
2. создать несколько репозиториев по количеству ваших модулей и подключить их как git-подмодули в под-каталоги в каталогах с вашими модулями.
3. создать один репозиторий (со структурой как в первом варианте) и подключить его в виде git-подмодуля в каждый из каталогов с вашими модулями.

в любом из этих вариантов придётся либо подправлять сборочные скрипты для указания изменившихся путей к файлам, либо использовать символические ссылки. но с символическими ссылками, насколько я знаю, возникают [некоторые проблемы в, например, операционной системе *ms/windows*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5917249/4827341).

---

**микро-инструкция по добавлению git-подмодулей**

чтобы добавить git-репозиторий (находящийся по адресу `url-репозитория`) как подмодуль в текущий репозиторий (в котором желательно не должно быть не закоммиченных изменений), выполните в нём команду:

```
$ git submodule add url-репозитория каталог/куда/добавлять
```

`каталог/куда/добавлять` не должен существовать на момент выполнения команды — он будет создан автоматически.

после выполнения этой команды в индекс будет автоматически добавлен `каталог/куда/добавлять` и новый (или модифицированный, если у вас уже были подключены какие-нибудь подмодули) файл `.gitmodules`:

```
$ git status

# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   new file:   .gitmodules
#   new file:   каталог/куда/добавлять
```

эти изменения нужно закоммитить. всё, подмодуль подключен.

если необходимо, можете отправлять изменения в «основной» репозиторий командой `push`. если «основным» репозиторием пользуетесь не только вы, то после выполнения в клонах этого репозитория команды `pull` (с вашим коммитом, добавляющим подмодуль), надо ещё выполнить две команды — `submodule init` и `submodule update`:

```
$ git submodule init
Submodule 'каталог/куда/добавлять' (url-репозитория) registered for path 'путь/куда/добавлять'
$ git submodule update
Cloning into 'путь/куда/добавлять'...
done.
Submodule path 'путь/куда/добавлять': checked out 'хэш коммита'
```