# GIT. Один репозиторий для 3х сайтов

Tags: git, gitlab

Всем привет. 
Есть несколько разных, но однотипных сайтов. 
У них есть одно ядро, заложено в папке core. 
Это ядро для всех сайтов должно быть одинаково. 
Остальные эелементы сайтов меняются.

Как сделать так, чтобы менять ядро в одном месте и сливать во все сайты?
Думал создать для этой папки отдельный репозиторий и от него клонировать все остальные сайты и создавать на гите для них отдельный репозиторий для каждого. Но как в таком случае обновлять? git pull не получится сделать же.

Comment: `git submodule`? Тынц [дока](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-Git-%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B8) и [подходящий вопрос на so](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/539683/213987) Делаете репозиторий core и ещё три репозитория под каждый сайт.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin у вас ссылка побилась

Comment: @PavelMayorov, это не у меня, а у нас. я ж не вручную это писал. ссылка: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/478100/178576 . баг-репорт написал: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6789/178576

Comment: @alexanderbarakin но это же не означает что ее нельзя вручную поправить

Comment: @PavelMayorov, для баг-репорта лучше оставить как есть.

Comment: т.е. если у меня таких папки 4, то придется делать 4 сабмодуля?

Comment: Ещё можно npm-пакет сделать, если там nodejs.